# Getting 'Before Update' document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, spring-data

Is there a way to get the 'before udpate' document in MongoDB via shell or through any frameworks like Spring Data [ Java ] ?

In some way can I set up a trigger that outputs two things when I hit update commands in MongoDB shell.

- print original document first
- print updated document

So far I have been exploring oplog contents but I am unable to do such a [triggerish] event as oplog's update entry has only those fields that are going to added/updated/removed to query criteria provided.

Comment: Not exactly. What is the overall purpose of this trigger? You can retrieve the document before you update it, but in a concurrent environment it could be changed between retrieval and update. You can potentially `findAndModify` with a `lock` field on the document to lock the document when you retrieve it. More explanation of how you will use this trigger and what's its overall purpose is will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) command takes an option (`new : true/false`) to specify whether you return the new version (true) or the original version of the document (false, this is the default).

Since you can have either version returned and you know what you are doing to modify the document, it should be possible to return the original (print it out), then apply the update to the document in your code and print it out again.

The alternative would be to use the original returned by `findAndModify`, then re-query for the same document, but you would have no way to guarantee that the document had not been changed by another operation in the meantime.

Comment: #Adam - findAndModify() seems handy. Thanks. Looking for the same through Spring framework if anyone has idea :)

Comment: I don't really know Spring, but this would seem to suggest that you have access to findAndModify: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#doFindAndModify-java.lang.String-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-com.mongodb.DBObject-java.lang.Class-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.FindAndModifyOptions-